# Undefined index: notify_read

Tags: php

I have this code on localhost it works perfect but does kick up this 1 error (php file)

line in question 
'pm_notify_read' => (int) $data['notify_read'],

the full section

```
$sql_ary = array();
    foreach ($recipients as $user_id => $type)
    {
        $sql_ary[] = array(
            'msg_id'        => (int) $data['msg_id'],
            'user_id'       => (int) $user_id,
            'author_id'     => (int) $data['from_user_id'],
            'pm_notify_read' => (int) $data['notify_read'],
            'folder_id'     => PRIVMSGS_NO_BOX,
            'pm_new'        => 1,
            'pm_unread'     => 1,
            'pm_forwarded'  => ($mode == 'forward') ? 1 : 0
        );
    }
```

Comment: Because that index does not exists. Please do a `print_r` on `$data`.

Comment: change this line to: 'pm_notify_read' => isset($data['notify_read']) ? (int) $data['notify_read'] : null,

Comment: 'pm_notify_read' => isset($data['notify_read']) ? (int) $data['notify_read'] : null,                                             

gives me a mysql error

Column 'pm_notify_read' cannot be null [1048]

Comment: 'pm_notify_read' => isset($data['notify_read']) ? (int) $data['notify_read'] : 1,

Seems to have solved it thank you very much for your help.